# how to fix TypeError: require(...) is not a function in fs discod.js v14

Tags: discord.js, node.js-fs

hello I had command handler in discord.js v14 its hosted in replit I opened my replit today after 3weeks and getting this error. Below is my index.js if want you can join my repl to help but please help me fix it as I have to get the bot on top.gg soon

```js
TypeError: require(...) is not a function
    at /home/runner/uniquegamer204/index.js:28:35
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/uniquegamer204/index.js:27:30)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
```

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Partials, Collection } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, 
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, 
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences, 
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions, 
        GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent
    ], 
    partials: [Partials.Channel, Partials.Message, Partials.User, Partials.GuildMember, Partials.Reaction] 
});

const fs = require('fs');
const config = require('./config.json');

client.commands = new Collection()
client.aliases = new Collection()
client.slashCommands = new Collection();
client.buttons = new Collection();
client.prefix = config.prefix;

module.exports = client;


fs.readdirSync('./handlers').forEach((handler) => {
  require(`./handlers/${handler}`)(client)
});
```

client.login(process.env.TOKEN)

Comment: So did your code work previously, and has 'without change' resulted in this error? If you DM me on Discord (ThatsLiamS#6950) I can join if you want.

Comment: You'll need to check every file inside your `handlers/` folder. Check if all of these files contain an exported function. At least one of them won't have it. :)

Comment: @ThatsLiamS thanks but Zsolt Meszaros was right I had an handler code dint work so I commented out everything but now I deleted it  thank you